# Python How to declare a class inside a method when it is required to be global

Tags: python, class-method, global-scope

I have the following function:

```
def create_figures():
    circle = figure()
    square = figure()
```

Then I have the following program:

```
create_figures()
circle.get_area()
```

The get_area() method is an error because circle doesn't exist in that scope, so my question is, how do I declare the circle class to be global in a nice pythonian way? I was thinking about declaring it at the top of the program like:

```
circle = figure()
```

and then just overwrite it in the create_figures() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do correct if I misunderstood your question but is this what you are looking for?

```
def create_figures():
    circle = figure()
    square = figure()
    return circle,square
```

And

```
circle,square = create_figures()
circle.get_area()
```

Edit:
Removed a typo